# Is it possible to change the filesystem type of the Compact Disc (CD) in linux using terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, cd, cd-drive

I have a new Compact Disc (CD) which is sony(rewritable) and its Filesystem type is UDF. Now it is possible to change it to CDFS filesystem using terminal commands or any other software?

The reason behind this is My car audio player pioneer is detecting and playing songs if CD in CDFS filesystem ..
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Using xfburn, I have the option to burn an audio CD or a data CD. Are you sure the disk is being burned as audio and not as data?

Comment: @mchid yes, I am sure.

Comment: First time hearing of cd having filesystem

Comment: @serg please look into this. http://disktype.sourceforge.net/doc/ch03s11.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is a software issue and not an issue with the actual disk, I believe you can achieve iso9660 format using xfburn:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfburn
xfburn --transcoder=basic
```

ref: [works with format iso9660](https://packages.debian.org/sid/xfce/xfburn)

&

```
:~$ xfburn --transcoder=list
Valid transcoders are:
    basic   Can only burn uncompressed CD quality .wav files.
    gst Uses gstreamer, and can burn all formats supported by it.
```

However, it may not be possible to not have a UFS burned disk as one of the advantages of UFS implementation over iso9660 is the ability to work with CD-RW disks as iso9660 is readonly and CD-RW is of course re-writable.

http://www.axis.com/files/tech_notes/cd_formats.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format